# Stuck fermentation, more yeast?

Tags: stuck-fermentation

I have a 2.5-2.75 gallon batch of Amber beer. I brewed it using the biab method. It's been in primary for about 2 weeks. 5 days ago the hydrometer reading was 1.030 and 3 days later it was 1.030. The OG 1.060 was and read after the wort was cooled in the kettle all night.

Mash temperature was 152 and cooled to about room temperature before adding yeast. Fermentation is done at room temperature which varies 65 and 80 around 70 average.

fermentables
5.5 Lb American pale 2 row
2 lb Crystal 40

yeast:
Safale 05
⅔ packet of yeast (.32 oz) dry 
Added about ¾ teaspoon of yeast Energizer

1. first question: should I add more yeast to restart the fermentation or is it done?
2. second question: Can I add the remaining 1/3 packet of us-05 yeast that's been sitting on my counter for 2 weeks? is it dead or unsanitary?

Comment: What is the fermentation temperature?

Comment: What was the mash temperature?

Comment: I added those details to the description.

Answer (score 3):

2lbs of crystal is likely the reason for the high FG.  Pull 500ml and add the rest of the yeast to that.  Keep it warm (75F or more), loosely covered and shake it/swirl it for a few days.  See if the gravity changes.  If it does you might be able to ferment the main batch a bit more.  If not then you know you are at terminal gravity.

Answer (score 2):

From what I read about it it seems your mash temperature has been too low on average.

You will end up with primarily maltose which isn't your yeast's favorite food, ergo, your ferment will be partial and your end product will likely taste sweet.

Comment: This makes sense.

Comment: Is there a way to test this (after the mash)?

Answer (score 1):

1I believe the fermentation is done.
2 don't add that yeast, it's dead.
Not one of your questions but letting your wort cool overnight is not a good idea.

Comment: 1.030 seems kind of high don't you think?

Comment: It was steady for 3 days, that a good sign that fermentation is completed.

Comment: Letting wort cool overnight is fine as long as sanitation is good.  Many people do it.  But it certainly would have no impact of final gravity in regards to the questions being asked.

Comment: The dried yeast left on the counter is not likely dead either.  Its not a best practice but there are plenty of shops that store it at room temperature.

Comment: So you are saying yeast, can survive for 2 weeks sitting on a countertop in the kitchen.

Comment: I stored 3 sacks of dried yeast in the fridge and when I needed some I noticed all were over a year past the use before date. 2 packs appeared to be dead, one still worked. This was all vacuumed stuff though. I would be surprised if keeping good dry yeast at room temperature for a couple of days would kill it..

Comment: A couple of days, I would think might be ok. But 2 weeks, I find it to be a stretch, that it would be good.